# A method to detect non-repetition relation when neo4j is inserted?

Tags: neo4j

My steps:

1. Read CSV to create node A
2. Make relational mapping with node B in Neo4j library
3. Read new CSV to add node A
4. Do relational mapping with node B in the library

So there's a new relationship repetition problem, how can we detect if it's repeated, and if it's repeated then we don't associate it

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQ0Mg.png)

My version is neo4j 3

Answer (score 0):

MATCH (p:lj_package),(v:lj_package_version)
WHERE p.lj_package=v.package_id and v.package_id='3982913' and not  (v)-[:IN]->(p)  return p,v ;
You only need to filter existing relationships when querying！

```
not  (v)-[:IN]->(p)
```